# angularJS/ionic cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, caching

I'm adding Caching to my App everything works fine from caching data, getting it expired and re-cache. When I implemented the functionality of putting the same expired data in the cache again if there is no connection I get this error: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Here is the code of my controller:

```
.controller('ItemsCtrl', function($scope, $http, DSCacheFactory) {

    //handle the catche to hold the items lits.
    self.itemsCache = DSCacheFactory.get("itemsCache");
    /*
    *Function to re-refresh the cach after expire
    *re-use the old cache if no internet connection available
    */
    self.itemsCache.setOptions({
        onExpire: function(key, value){
            getItems()
                .then(function(){
                console.log("Items Cache was automatically refreshed", new Date());
            }, function(){
                console.log("Errorgetting data put expired item back in the cache", new Date());
            });
        }
    });

    function getItems(){
        var cacheKey = "items",
            itemsData = self.itemsCache.get(cacheKey);
        if(itemsData){
            // if data in the cache dont make  HTTP calls.
            console.log("Found Data in cache", itemsData);
            //recive Data from the cache
            $scope.items = itemsData;
        }
        else{//if no data in the catch make HTTP calls.
            //HTTP request to get the items data.
            $http.get('services/data.json')
             .success(function(data){
                console.log("Recived data via HTTP");
                //caching the data recived from the http calls.
                self.itemsCache.put(cacheKey, data);
                $scope.items = data;
            });
        }//end of the else statment
    }
    getItems();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The function getItems isn't returning anything - it looks like you meant to return a promise so it should be something like below.

When you find the item in the cache you can use $q.when to create a promise that's already resolved when the parameter isn't a promise.

When you don't find it, you can return the chained promise from $http.get.

```
.controller('ItemsCtrl', function($scope, $http, DSCacheFactory, $q) {

    //handle the cache to hold the items list.
    self.itemsCache = DSCacheFactory.get("itemsCache");
    /*
    *Function to re-refresh the cache after expire
    *re-use the old cache if no internet connection available
    */
    self.itemsCache.setOptions({
        onExpire: function(key, value){
            getItems()
                .then(function(itemsData){
                console.log("Items Cache was automatically refreshed", new Date());
            }, function(){
                console.log("Error getting data put expired item back in the cache", new Date());
            });
        }
    });

    function getItems(){
        var cacheKey = "items",
            itemsData = self.itemsCache.get(cacheKey);
        if(itemsData){
            // if data in the cache dont make  HTTP calls.
            console.log("Found Data in cache", itemsData);
            //receive Data from the cache
            $scope.items = itemsData;
            return $q.when(itemsData);
        }
        else{//if no data in the catch make HTTP calls.
            //HTTP request to get the items data.
            return $http.get('services/data.json')
             .success(function(data){
                console.log("Received data via HTTP");
                //caching the data received from the http calls.
                self.itemsCache.put(cacheKey, data);
                $scope.items = data;
                return data;
            });
        }//end of the else statement
    }
    getItems();
})
```

Comment: i tried your solution it didn't work, i also try to apply the concept in diffrent way als, didnt work still infinate HTTP calls and the same error of undifined ill post my soultion that didn't work as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work I just didn't want to ruin the question.

```
.controller('ItemsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q, DSCacheFactory) {

        //handle the cache to hold the items lits.
        self.itemsCache = DSCacheFactory.get("itemsCache");
        /*
        *Function to re-refresh the cache after expire
        *re-use the old cache if no internet connection available
        */
        self.itemsCache.setOptions({
            onExpire: function(key, value){
                getItems()
                    .then(function(){
                    console.log("Items Cache was automatically refreshed", new Date());
                }, function(){
                    console.log("Errorgetting data put expired item back in the cache", new Date());
                });
            }
        });

        function getItems(){
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                cacheKey = "items",
                itemsData = self.itemsCache.get(cacheKey);

            if(itemsData){
                // if data in the cache dont make  HTTP calls.
                console.log("Found Data in cache", itemsData);
                //receive Data from the cache
                $scope.items = itemsData;
                deferred.resolve(itemsData);
            }
            else{//if no data in the catch make HTTP calls.
                //HTTP request to get the items data.
                $http.get('services/data.json')
                 .success(function(data){
                    console.log("Received data via HTTP");
                    //caching the data received from the http calls.
                    self.itemsCache.put(cacheKey, data);
                    $scope.items = data;
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
            }//end of the else statement
        }
        getItems();
    })
```